# How to fire TextBox change event when value is changed using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a simple html textbox. I am using Jquery to fire textbox textchanged event. The problem I am facing is that it works onlywhen user enters text using keyboard or copy paste. But it never works when the value of the textbox is changed using javascript or Jquery.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JWd4Y/)

**Markup**

```
  <input type='text' class="expensehead"  />
<button id="btn">Set Value</button>
```

**Script**

```
$(".expensehead").on('change keyup paste', function() {
    alert("text changed");
});
$("#btn").on('click', function() {
  $(".expensehead").val('123');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the event at the time of setting the value

```
$("#btn").on('click', function() {
  $(".expensehead").val('123').change();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JWd4Y/1/)

Comment: you cant chain since `.val()` would not return a jquery object.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy can you check the demo?

Comment: sorry i was wrong, in a thought of retrieving the values.

Comment: I know I can change call this event at the time of changing the value but I was just wondering if there is a way to detect text changed without explicitly calling change event.